# spark maven jar file dependency

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I have used Eclipse with Maven, Java and Scala to develop a simple Spark application.
Under the target folder, Maven install command has created two JAR files one named as **application.jar** and the other one named as **application-with-dependencies.jar**. My question is which JAR file I should use to submit it to the Spark cluster? Also, why there are two JAR files? The file called  **application.jar**  is fraction of the size **application-with-dependencies.jar**

Answer (score 2):

Maven usually generates a JAR file containing only your compiled classes and resources, but using some plugins, like [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), maven can also generate an uber-jar, i.e.: a JAR file that contains not only your classes and resources, but also libraries your project depends on.

Without more information `application-with-dependencies-jar` looks like one of those uber-jar.

From [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) looks like that's the JAR you must submit to the Spark cluster.

Comment: thanks, application-with-dependencies-jar is 100MB in size compared to only 6KB application.jar